# Front page in document class book not centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, geometry, book-design

I'm using the document class book and I am designing my front page atm.

I try it like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
FRONT PAGE \\
\end{center}

\newpage

\chapter{First chapter}

Foo

\end{document}
```

But this way it isn't really centered.. It's a bit on the left side, isn't it?

I hope you know this issue and know how to fix it!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The centering is working.  `book` class sets up large margins on alternate sides of the page for binding purposes.  If you use `\usepackage{showframe}` that will show you how the margins are set and you'll be able to see that your `center` environment is working.  If you want to override the `book` class defaults and change the margins, you can use the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

define another page layout for the first page:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\savegeometry{origin}
\geometry{rmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm}% for the title page
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}    
\begin{center}
FRONT PAGE 
\end{center}

\loadgeometry{origin}% restore the orign margin setting
\chapter{First chapter}
Foo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how can I make the borders invisible?

Comment: ah. I got it... By using "\usepackage{geometry}". Thanks very much for your help!!!